# DateTime from SQL Server with timezone

Tags: c#, sql-server, date, datetime, timezone

When I execute a query and access the value using DataReader and converting it to string, I don't get the TimeZone(2015-02-17T00:00:00).

But on creating a DataSet and then converting it to XML, I get the TimeZone in the DateTime field(2015-02-17T00:00:00+11:00).

The code to retrieve the data from the datareader is `var dateTime = reader["dte_tme"].ToString()` which yields `17/02/2015 12:00:00 AM` (without TimeZone).

```
string dateTime = reader["dte_tme"].ToString();
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime);
```

So I know that the field 'dte_tme' is a DateTime field which may not always have a value. I'm converting it to a string and then converting it back to DateTime. The value of `dt` is then serialized into a json. And the output that I get is `2015-02-17T00:00:00` instead of `2015-02-17T00:00:00+11:00`. I checked the TimeZone of `dt` and it is `Unspecified`.

The DateTime object that I create from the XML from DataSet has TimeZone as `Local` which serializes to `2015-02-17T00:00:00+11:00`.

Why is this inconsistency?

Also, is there a way to get the DateTime with TimeZone using DataReader?

My ultimate goal is to serialize the DateTime field in ISO 8601 format.

Comment: What do you use to convert the `DataSet` to xml?

Comment: @KeithPayne DataSet ds = GetDataSet(blah, blah); var xml = dataSet.GetXml();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very common anti-pattern:

```
string dateTime = reader["dte_tme"].ToString();
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime);
```

The correct incantation is as follows:

```
DateTime dt = (DateTime) reader["dte_tme"];
```

While the return type of `reader["dte_time"]` is an `object`, that object contains a `DateTime`.  If you set a breakpoint, you'd see the `DateTime` is already there.  You just need to [cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms173105.aspx) it so it can be assigned to a `DateTime` variable.  This is called [*unboxing*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/yz2be5wk.aspx).

If the `datetime` column in the SQL database is nullable, then you should test for that like this:

```
DateTime? dt = reader["dte_tme"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (DateTime) reader["dte_tme"];
```

Or sometimes you will see it like this, which is equally acceptable:

```
DateTime? dt = reader["dte_tme"] as DateTime?;
```

It absolutely does *not* need to be treated as a string at any point when retrieving it from the database.  If it's a `datetime` in the database, then it's a `DateTime` in C#.

You should use a casting operation when pulling data from a datareader, even with other data types such as integers, decimals, *and even strings*.  You can see other type mappings between SQL Server data types and .NET data types [in the chart here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx).

Now with regard to time zone, that's a different issue.  First, understand that `DateTime` doesn't keep a time zone.  It only has knowledge of the `DateTimeKind` it is assigned.  By default, the kind is `Unspecified`, which essentially means, "I don't know; it could be anything".

That said, different protocols have different requirements.  JSON has no predefined format for dates, but the most common convention (and best practice) is to store a date in [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, which is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss`.  Time zone information is *optional*, and will usually not be included when the `.Kind` of a `DateTime` is `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.  If it were `Utc`, then you would see a `Z` at the end, and if it were `Local`, then you would see an offset of the local time zone, such as `+11:00`.  That is, whatever offset is appropriate for that time zone, *at that particular moment*.  An offset is not the same thing as a "[time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)", because different offset could apply within the same time zone at different times - usually to [daylight saving time](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info).

XML is a bit different.  Most of the XML serialization in .NET will use the [W3C XML Schema](http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema) specification, and will map a `DateTime` to an [`xsd:dateTime`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#dateTime) type.  How exactly it is rendered will depend on the `Kind`.

- For `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, it will not include an offset.
- For `DateTimeKind.Utc`, it will append a `Z`
- For `DateTimeKind.Local`, it will append the local offset

You asked why the `Kind` is `Local` when you look at it in the dataset?  That's because `DataSet` has an ugly behavior of assuming that all times are local.  It essentially ignores the `.Kind` property and assumes the behavior of `DateTimeKind.Local`.  This is a longstanding bug.

Ideally, you would use a `datetimeoffset` type in SQL Server, and a `DateTimeOffset` type in .NET.  This avoids the "kind" issues, and serializes nicely in JSON (when you use modern serializers like [JSON.NET](http://json.net)).  In XML, however, it *should* get mapped to `xsd:dateTime` and rendered just like the local `DateTime` did, just with the correct offset.  However it instead ends up looking like this:

```
<Value xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System">
    <d2p1:DateTime>2015-03-18T03:34:11.3097587Z</d2p1:DateTime>
    <d2p1:OffsetMinutes>-420</d2p1:OffsetMinutes>
</Value>
```

That's with `DataContractXmlSerializer`.  If you use the `XmlSerializer`, you it can't render at all.  You just get an empty node, such as `<Value/>`.

However, even with all of that said, you said you were using `DataSet`, and that comes with it's own set of behaviors.  On the bad side, it will assume that all `DateTime` values have `DateTimeKind.Local` - even when they don't, as I mentioned above.  Consider the following:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Foo", typeof (DateTime));

dt.Rows.Add(new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified));
dt.Rows.Add(new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local));
dt.Rows.Add(new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc));

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
string xml = ds.GetXml();

Debug.Write(xml);
```

This is the output when I run it (in the US Pacific time zone):

```xml
<NewDataSet>
  <Table1>
    <Foo>2015-01-01T00:00:00-08:00</Foo>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <Foo>2015-01-01T00:00:00-08:00</Foo>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <Foo>2015-01-01T00:00:00-08:00</Foo>
  </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

However, the good news is that `DateTimeOffset` values are a little better:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Foo", typeof(DateTimeOffset));

dt.Rows.Add(new DateTimeOffset(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.FromHours(11)));
dt.Rows.Add(new DateTimeOffset(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero));
dt.Rows.Add(new DateTimeOffset(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.FromHours(-3)));

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
string xml = ds.GetXml();

Debug.Write(xml);
```

Output:

```xml
<NewDataSet>
  <Table1>
    <Foo>2015-01-01T00:00:00+11:00</Foo>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <Foo>2015-01-01T00:00:00Z</Foo>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <Foo>2015-01-01T00:00:00-03:00</Foo>
  </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

For the most part, this is correct, though *technically* it should have serialized the second one using `+00:00` instead of `Z`, but that's not going to matter all that much in practice.

The last thing I'd just like to say is that in general, `DataSet` is a relic from the past.  In modern development, there should be very little need to use it in your day to day code.  If possible, I would seriously consider exploring other options.

Comment: Casting the value will throw exception as not all the records will have values in the field. Instead, I parsed the string to DateTime and created another DateTime with DateTimeKind as Local and converted that to universal time which is what I need to serialize via json.

Comment: I updated the answer to include how to deal with nulls.  You should never have to go to a string there.  Also, if you want to change the kind, just use `DateTime.SpecifyKind`.  You don't have to go to string there either.   With regard to json - you didn't really explain what you're doing there or gave any code sample, so I'm not sure I can help without additional info.

Comment: @Matt - possible alternative to :  DateTime? dt = reader["dte_tme"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (DateTime) reader["dte_tme"];    
      is :  DateTime? dt = reader["dte_tme"] as DateTime?;

Answer (score 1):

The time zone information is not stored in the `DateTime` data type, it's stored in the [`DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=netframework-4.7.2) data type.  When you convert to `DateTime`, you're stripping the time zone from the data.  Try using `DateTimeOffset` instead.  See this thread for more info:

[DateTimeOffset resolution in c# and SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255387/datetimeoffset-resolution-in-c-sharp-and-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `DataSet.GetXml()` and other xml-writing methods of DataSet share a ugly problem of assuming that the `datetime` value is a local time. It uses the timezone setting of the machine where the code executes.

The MS workarounds to fix it are equally ugly. From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/03/07/387677.aspx :

> DataSet is the hardest technology of the three to work around this problem. 
>   Some options:
>       1. Change the column types to be Int64 or String
>
> ```
> 2. Call DateTime.ToLocalTime on the DateTime before putting it in the DataSet and call DateTime.ToUniversalTime after taking it out. This will  effectively “cancel out” the adjustment, and can be used whether you are dealing with a whole date or a UTC time.
> ```
>
> 3. Make all machines use the same time zone.
> 4. Use Remoting to serialize the DataSet in binary form. This also has performance benefits. This KB article has an example.
> 5. If you have a chance to pre-process the XML before it is sent out, you can manually strip out the time zone offset out of the XML text. For example, a typical XML date and time looks like this: “2005-01-28T03:14:42.0000000-07:00”. You can use a Regex to remove the “-07:00”. You do not need to re-inject anything on the other end, as no adjustment is made if there is no time zone information. Do not try to replace the time zone offset with “Z” or “+00:00”. While technically a more correct representation, the existence of time zone information will cause the serializer to do an extra conversion to local.
>
> This is the most difficult situation, because all of these work-arounds have problems. Option (1) involves bypassing the database type system. Option (2) has a reliability caveat explained below. I would actually recommend (4) or (5) for this technology.

Comment: another way to remove timezones from DataSet XML serialization (for .net 2.0 or later) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932071/custom-datetime-formats-when-using-dataset-writexml-in-net/6935884#6935884

Comment: The DataSet in question actually gets filled up by a DataAdapter using `dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet)` method. I used `DateTime.SpecifyKind` to set the `DateTimeKind` of the DateTime object and then converting it to UTC kind by calling `dateTime.ToUniversalTime()`.